# How can I use Ghostscript to convert XPS to PDF or XPS to DOC?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, doc, xps

Which one is the best third party libary to convert XPS to PDF and XPS to DOC.

Comment: In OS X you can run `brew install libgxps` and then run `xpstopdf input.xps output.pdf` to convert XPS to PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XPS to PDF:**
You can use GhostXPS (part of [GhostPDL](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/)):

```
gxps.exe ^
 -o output.pdf ^
  c:/path/to/input.xps
```

Comment: Not working in newer version of GhostXPS

Answer (score 27):

While gxps and ghostscript are a possible solution, the syntax of the accepted answer did not work for me.

I was able to use ghostscript and gxps using the following syntax:

```
C:\gxps-871.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=myfile.pdf -dNOPAUSE myfile.xps
```

One comment on tab path completion:
gxps doesn't seem to understand some of the Windows 7 symbolic links like My Documents well.  If you have trouble tab-completing to your path, consider a temp folder in c:.

Credit where credit is due: I got this syntax from this blog:
http://minhtech.com/windows/convert-xps-to-pdf-without-printer-driver/

Comment: I agree, this is the correct answer so far (at least for what concerns XPS to PDF conversion)

Comment: Linking to [another possible syntax to do the same thing using GhostXPS](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18460/15456)

Comment: I liked GhostScript, unfortuntately, its license is GPL, so in practice in many cases it cannot be used..